# Add css to cms page doesn't work

Tags: magento2, css, layout-update, cms-pages

I want to add css from module to my custom cms page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Test_Customlayout::css/test.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test" before="header">
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">23</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
           <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

but I've got an error like this while I'm trying to save the page:

```
Please correct the XML data and try again. XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Line: 1
```

Comment: ` start of the document Line: 1` means there have some space before start `<?xml `,Please write `<?xml version="1.0"?>` before start amlny code in x

Comment: @AmitBera i already make sure there's no space before start

Answer (score 0):

Within layout update XML for CMS page there is no need for a lot of this code. Try below?

```
    <head>
      <css src="Test_Customlayout::css/test.css" /> 
    </head>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test" before="header">
          <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">23</argument>
          </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
       <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

This saved fine in my 2.1.7 version of Magento.

Comment: i'm using 2.1.8 and i got the following error : `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`

Comment: Is this within the CMS page -> Design Tab -> Layout Update XML?

Comment: yes, fill it in that field for sure

Comment: That is strange i remember this error happening to me a while back not sure why it works fine for me now however.